# Azure AD B2C userflow replace autorizaion code from identity provider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

**Setup**

I have a identity provider that gives me an accesstoken and a auterization code that I have connected to a B2C userflow.

**Problem**

For some reason the userflow replaces the autorizaion code from the identity provider.

By looking at the responce from fiddler one can see that the provided code(FNIwnd....) is replaced with a unknown code(eyJraW....) in the three last reponces.

[image: Userflow responce from fiddler]

A virtual kiss/highfive or solid handshake to anyone who knows what this is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAD B2C trades your identity providers authZ code for a token. It happens on our server side, so your client trace doesn’t capture that. If successful, this means the user is who they say they are at the IdP.

Then AAD B2C issues it’s own authZ code back to the app, and the app trades that authZ code for AAD B2C tokens.

AAD B2C (App/RP) <-> Your IdP (IdP)
Your app (App/RP) <-> AAD B2C (IdP)

AAD B2C is acting as an app and an IdP in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by enriching the adtoken with the idp accesstoken.